# Can't search item in Array of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image: Array of Object Image]

```
var secondVariations;
```

this is the array of object name what you are seeing in the image.

I have the above Array of Object.
But I can't search an item in this. What is the problem?

It's giving me `undefined`

```
let value_of_select = 7;
let variationListTargettedValueOfSelect = secondVariations.find(obj => {
       return obj.id === value_of_select;
});
```

I also used `filter` but same result!
What my mistake?

Code Structure:

```
var secondVariations;
$.ajax({
   -----
   success:function(response){
      secondVariations = response;
});

// I have a select-option in success {} block. After firing this 

$(document).on('change', '.select-class' , function(){
let value_of_select = 7;
let variationListTargettedValueOfSelect = secondVariations.find(obj => {
       return obj.id === value_of_select;
});
});
```

Comment: `console.log(variationListTargettedValueOfSelect )` what prints?

Comment: Are you assigning the variable in an async function?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Can you share the entire function where you are using this.

Comment: Include a reproducable example.

Comment: you should post the snippet code completely to see what is going on

Comment: @Berto99, giving me `variationListTargettedValueOfSelect ` undefined

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added my code Structure.
Actually it's very big code to share.

Comment: @Barmar you got it ahaha

Comment: @AspileInc Barmar will probably explain it on a answer, but to sum up, `$.ajax` is async, and so `filter` might me executed before the `success` callback is fired

Comment: You need to put the filter code in the `success` function.

Comment: Oh. Then I am going to Brute Force method. `for` loop. It's a better solution now. But I don't know about the complexity!! :-D